# ASIHTTP Cache POST GET

Tags: iphone, ios, json, asihttprequest

I would like to use ASIHTTP to manage caching some JSON requests.
Originally I though all I had to do was this:

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
```

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

However after testing I can see that nothing is being cached.
I think this is because ASI cacheing only works with GET and I'm using POST.
I want to try sending a GET but I can see how.
I've tried setting the request method but no change.

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm having the exact same issue and can't find a proper solution... I've messing around with the ASIHTTPRequest.m class and haven't had any success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different cache policy using `setCachePolicy`.

With `ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy` you can enforce to use the cached response if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

Find  this in ASIDownloadCache.m.

```
if (![[self requestMethod] isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        [self setDownloadCache:nil];
    }
```

Now you can use cache with POST method.